# Can i use Lucene Search for indexing and Searching Tamil Documents?

Tags: java, lucene

I need to search a tamil document based on certain rules, will i be able to use LUcene search. Will it support Tamil language?

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not really familiar specifically with Tamil, by my understanding, [`StandardAnalyzer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html) should support it reasonably well.  It is multi-lingual, and implements [UAX #29](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/), which should provide good text segmentation and normalization for all Indic languages.

I'm not aware of any Tamil specific analysis package, to provide stemming and the like, though there might be some useful components in [org.apache.lucene.analysis.in](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/in/package-summary.html).